# How can I give proper indentation to the text staring on second line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what i am getting:

[image: Error Image]

I just want padding space between input and the label and also on the second line. I am trying to give padding on the second line.

Below is my code:

```
   <div class="test">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question1" name="2question" title="Merknaam 1" /> <label for="2question1">Very long text which is wrapped on the next line</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question2" name="2question" title="Merknaam 2" /> 
       <label for="2question2">Merknaam 2</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question3" name="2question" title="Merknaam 3" />  <label for="2question3">Merknaam 3</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question4" name="2question" title="Merknaam 4" />  <label for="2question4">Merknaam 4</label><br>
    </div>


    .test {
        width:200px;
    }

    .test label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 1em;
        text-indent: -1em;
    }
```

Comment: It does have padding, what exactly do you want this to look like? I'm guessing you want the second line to be even with the first.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was not easy at all. They key was adding `display: inline-block;` to the parent container. Try this:

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.test input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.test label {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 1em;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question1" name="2question" title="Merknaam 1" /> <label for="2question1">Very long text which is wrapped on the next line Very long text which is wrapped on the next line</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question2" name="2question" title="Merknaam 2" /> 
       <label for="2question2">Merknaam 2</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question3" name="2question" title="Merknaam 3" />  <label for="2question3">Merknaam 3</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="2question4" name="2question" title="Merknaam 4" />  <label for="2question4">Merknaam 4</label><br>
    </div>
```

You can make some adjustments to the `.test{padding-left}` and `.test input{margin-left}` to get the desired result.

Comment: Can this be done through JQuery or CSS? I can't edit html due to some limitations.

Comment: @Rehankhan Ok, that's good to know. I'll see what I can do. I'll edit the answer in a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for you help bro

Comment: Hey dude, one more requirement is that for the first input, the text and the label should be aligned horizontally.

Comment: Bro. i am in a bit urgency. Can you try this ASAP

Comment: @Rehankhan I updated the answer a while ago. Please check the updated css.

Comment: Sure bro, let me check

Comment: See i have posted an image with the result now.

Comment: @Rehankhan on the image you posted, there is a 51px left-padding on the label. I do not know where that is coming from, that is the issue. All you have to do is override that and you should be alright.

Comment: When i change the padding, it is only getting affected on the first line. but not on the second line